# Removing enum flags

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation

I'm a little bit puzzled by the removal of enum flags to be perfectly honest.

Let me make an example, let's say we have an enum that looks like this

```
[Flags]
enum Letter 
{
    A = 1, // 1
    B = 2, // 10
    C = 4  // 100
}
```

Now if I want to make a variable hold the flags `Letter.AB` I could do `foo = Letter.A | Letter.B`. Now this makes sense to me, I can calculate this and it will make sense:

```
   01
OR 10
 = 11 = 3 = 1 + 2 = A + B = AB
```

When it comes to removing flags, I am puzzled however, intuitively what I would like to do is use the *XOR* operator to do so, like this:

```
bar = Letter.A | Letter.B | Letter.C // Set bar to ABC
// Now let's remove everything but Letter.C
bar = bar ^ (Letter.A | Letter.B)
```

Calculating this by hand should yield:

```
    111
XOR 011
  = 100 = 4 = C = ABC - (A + B) = 7 - (1 + 2)
```

But this isn't what people seem to do when they are removing enum flags, they use the *AND* operator which makes absolutely no sense to me. Is there any drawback to using the *XOR* operator for removing enum flags? There must obviously be something I'm not seeing here, so a detailed clarification would be appreciated greatly! :)

Comment: XOR is a toggle so you have to make sure A and B are set before you XOR them - otherwise you could be setting them! AND with a mask lets you zero our the stuff you don't want, leaving everything else.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the problem with the XOR operator is that unless you *know* that you've got all the rest of the flags, it will just flip them. So your XOR operation isn't "remove all but C" - it's "toggle the values of A and B". (So if the input was "A,C" you'd end up with "B,C", for example.)

`&` is used because it's *masking*. The basic idea is that you get a value which contains just the bits you want, and then a bitwise AND of that value with your input value masks it.

To remove one specific flag (rather than retaining that specific flag), you'd typically use the `~` operator to create a mask of "all but that flag". For example:

```
var mask = ~Letter.A;
var newValue = originalValue & mask; // All previous values other than A
```

Comment: Wouldn't using the *AND* operation just retrieve that value if it exists and if not return nothing? I must admit I am not sure of what the `~` operator does.

Comment: @OverlyExcessive: It does that *for each bit of the value* (it's a bitwise operator). It sounds like you should probably review a tutorial (or book coverage) of bitwise operators and just experiment with various options until you understand.