# C# removing enum flag?

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand this line:

```
engagement.BilledAuditTiers &= ~engagementTier;
```

- BilledAuditTiers is enum field of the object engagement
- engagementTier is given enum value

Is this removing given enum value's flag?

Comment: Yes. This is equivalent to `engagement.BilledAuditTiers = engagement.BilledAuditTiers & ~engagementTier` where `&` is the binary AND operator and `~` is the binary NOT operator.

Comment: E.g. in binary `101010 & ~(000010)` → `101010 & 111101` → `101000`

Comment: Duplicate of [Removing enum flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307124/removing-enum-flags)

Comment: @EricLippert: Am I missing something? I don't think `Enum.RemoveFlag` was ever implemented ( https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/693 has been open since 2015 ).  The only flag manipulation we have is [Enum.HasFlag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag).

Comment: @Brian: I am misremembering. I thought it had been implemented. Because it is an obviously good thing to do and low cost. Vexing that it has not been!

Comment: I deleted my earlier wrong comment; let me say instead: it would be a good idea to implement a helper function `RemoveFlag` that does this math for you. That would make the code obvious to the reader; since you had to ask a question about it, evidently it was not obvious!